# How to show only 5 items in wishlist Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

On customer account I only want to show just 5 items of wishlist.
How can I do this ?  item.phtml is

```
<div class="products-grid wishlist">
    <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
    <?php if (count($block->getItems())): ?>
    <ol class="product-items">
        <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $item): ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li data-row="product-item" class="product-item" id="item_' . $item->getId() . '">' : '</li><li class="product-item" id="item_' . $item->getId() . '">' ?>
            <div class="product-item-info">
                <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
                    <?php $column->setItem($item); echo $column->toHtml($item);?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <?php echo($iterator == count($block->getItems())+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="message info empty">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('This Wish List has no Items');?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
    <?php echo $column->getAdditionalHtml();?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to show only 5 items or want to show pagination for more than 5 items?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya  I want to show only 5 items.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="products-grid wishlist">
    <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
    <?php if (count($block->getItems())): ?>
    <ol class="product-items">
        <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $item): ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li data-row="product-item" class="product-item" id="item_' . $item->getId() . '">' : '</li><li class="product-item" id="item_' . $item->getId() . '">' ?>
            <div class="product-item-info">
                <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
                    <?php $column->setItem($item); echo $column->toHtml($item);?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <?php echo($iterator == count($block->getItems())+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
        <?php if($iterator > 5): break; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="message info empty">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('This Wish List has no Items');?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
    <?php echo $column->getAdditionalHtml();?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: is this tested ?

Comment: No its not tested, but it should work. Let me know if you face any issue with the code.